# I have oracle database data in diffrent time format stored need to change to another time format

Tags: oracle, datetime

I have date formate like  20111125101924Z. I need to remove Z and need to made this format like DD/MM/YYYY/hr/mn/sec

Comment: What data type is the original value? It looks like you're storing dates as strings, but it could just be how your client is displaying dates.

Answer (score 2):

A `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` data type are binary formats (consisting of 1 byte for each of century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second and for timestamp may also have up to 6 bytes for fractional seconds and/or 7 bytes for time zone) and they do **NOT** have a format.

Therefore, if you are trying to copy from `DATE` to `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` to `TIMESTAMP` then you do not need to do anything; any differences in how they are displayed is purely cosmetic and can be modified by changing the session variables or settings on whatever client user interface you are using to view the database.

For example, in SQL/Plus (and SQL Developer), you can use the session parameter `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` to change how a date is displayed and your two formats would be:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYYHH24:MI:SS';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS"Z"';
```

If you are storing the values as strings then

- don't do that, change the data type to `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`.
- if you must then change it using `TO_DATE` and `TO_CHAR`:

  ```
  TO_CHAR(
    TO_DATE(
      '20111125101924Z',
      'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS"Z"'
    ),
    'DD/MM/YYYYHH24MISS'
  )
  ```
- Or, for `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`:

  ```
  TO_CHAR(
    TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
      '20111125101924Z',
      'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSTZR'
    ),
    'DD/MM/YYYYHH24MISS'
  )
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, I assume your column is of string data type

```sql
select 
  to_char( 
    to_date(REPLACE('20111125101924Z', 'Z'), 'YYYYMMDDHHMISS')
    , 'DD/MM/YYYY/HH/MI/SS') 
from dual
;
```